# Why does DotNetZip cause OutOfMemory Exception in Images?

Tags: c#, image, dotnetzip

I have tried zipping an .PNG image file to a zip file using DotNetZip but after I extract it later on and use the Image.FromFile method it gives me an OutOfMemory Exception. I have tried other images but it gives me the same result. If I override the image with the file that wasn't zipped I don't get that error.

**Compression Code**

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = system.Abriviation + " Game|*" + system.Extention;
sfd.AddExtension = true;
sfd.ShowDialog();

if (sfd.FileName != "")
{

    StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\meta");
    write.WriteLine(txtName.Text);
    write.WriteLine(new FileInfo(txtGame.Text).Extension);
    write.WriteLine(txtCompany.Text);
    write.Close();

    File.Copy(txtGame.Text, Application.StartupPath + "\\game" + new FileInfo(txtGame.Text).Extension);
    File.Copy(txtGame.Text, Application.StartupPath + "\\icon.png");

    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
    zip.AddFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\meta", "");
    zip.AddFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\game" + new FileInfo(txtGame.Text).Extension, "");
    zip.AddFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\icon.png", "");
    zip.Save(sfd.FileName);
    zip.Dispose();

    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\game" + new FileInfo(txtGame.Text).Extension);
    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\icon.png");
    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\meta");

    Close();
}
```

**Extraction Code**

```
ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file);
bool foundMeta = false;
String id = "";
foreach(ZipEntry e in zip){
    if (e.FileName == "meta")
    {
        e.Extract(Application.StartupPath);
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\meta");
        id = read.ReadLine();
        read.Close();
        File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\meta");
        foundMeta = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (foundMeta)
{
    if (!GameSystem.Exists(id))
    {
        zip.ExtractAll(Main.Library.Path + "\\" + id.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Main.Library.Path + "\\" + id.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower() + "\\Games");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Main.Library.Path + "\\" + id.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower() + "\\Games\\metas");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("System " + id + " is already added.", "8 Bit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not find the meta file.", "8 Bit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
zip.Dispose();

return GameSystem.Load(Main.Library.Path + "\\" + id.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower());
```

**Image Loading Code**

```
String name = "", company = "", ext = "";
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(file);
name = read.ReadLine();
ext = read.ReadLine();
company = read.ReadLine();
read.Close();

Image icon = null;
if (File.Exists(system.GameMetaPath + "\\" + info.Name + ".png"))
{
    icon = Image.FromFile(system.GameMetaPath + "\\" + info.Name + ".png");
    //The error happens on the line above.
}

return new Game(system, name, company, system.GamePath + "\\" + info.Name + ext, file, icon);
```

Is there a way to get around or fix this problem?

Comment: This could be due to your lack of `using` blocks.

Comment: Well these two blocks of code don't happen at the same time. They happen at two different times in my application.

Comment: I couldn't find a suggestion that applied because it isn't large at all and it can be opened in other programs.

Comment: I may be being really dense here but I do not see where you are extracting the files from the ZipFile using DotNetZip, all I see is you using standard File IO.

Comment: -1: As @MarkHall said there is no unzipping portion which should be causing the issue.